# Can not understand the bellow util method, who can help me with a explaintion?

Tags: javascript

I downloaded a util file, but I cannot understand the `util` method, who can help me with a explaintion?

```
util.inOf = function (arr, targetArr) {
  let res = true;
  arr.map(item => {
    if (targetArr.indexOf(item) < 0) {
      res = false;
    }
  });
  return res;
};

util.oneOf = function (ele, targetArr) {
  if (targetArr.indexOf(ele) >= 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: What do you think it does? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first function is terribly written code. It uses `map` but doesn't map or return anything. The first function tests to see if every subarr in `arr` exists in `targetArr` - if so, it returns `true`, else, it returns false.

The second function just tests to see if the `ele` is in the targetArr. If so, it returns true, if not, it returns false.

This is what the first function *should* look like:

```
util.inOf = function (arr, targetArr) {
  return arr.every(item => targetArr.includes(item));
};
```

and the second function is equivalent to

```
util.oneOf = function (ele, targetArr) {
  return targetArr.includes(ele);
};
```